# PHP how to send USR1 signal to process?

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I need to send a USR1 signal to a daemon from a PHP script.  I'm using posix_kill($pid, SIGUSR1);, but SIGUSR1 is undefined.  Where do I import this constant from?

TY,
Fred

Comment: Hmm, normally it's there, but you might check out your signal documentation (for me SIGUSR1 is defined as 10, but 30 & 16 also work)

Comment: I am a PHP newbie, are constants like that automagically defined, i.e. you don't need to #include them from a file like in C?

Comment: no, if you have posix enabled the constants will be automatically defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nikic is right.  If you have PCNTL [installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.installation.php) properly, it should be [predefined](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pcntl.constants.php).  There is no need for any import.

Comment: OK, I am running the latest Ubuntu and installed php5 with apt-get.  To get the PCNTL stuff to work does that mean I have to uninstall it then re-build PHP from source?

Comment: @fred, one option is a third-party package.  I'm actually using Ubuntu Karmic, but with PHP 5.3 from the [dotdeb repos](http://www.dotdeb.org/instructions/), which have this enabled.  However, you can also just build PCNTL as a module from the Ubuntu source.  This [blog post](http://www.crimulus.com/2010/07/30/howto-enable-pcntl-in-ubuntu-php-installations/) has clear instructions.